# How to Combine IN-Opeator with LookupIds in a caml-query?

Tags: list, caml-query, lookup-column

I want to build a CAML - Query using the IN - Tag. The queried Column is a lookup-field to a Title of another list. When I query using the text-property everything works fine:

```
   <Where>
      <In>
         <FieldRef Name='page' />
         <Values>
            <Value Type='Lookup'>page1</Value>
            <Value Type='Lookup'>page2</Value>
            <Value Type='Lookup'>page3</Value>
         </Values>
      </In>
   </Where>
```

This is giving me the wanted result: All rows with Lookups to page1, page2 oder page3 are returned.

When I try to achieve this using the IDs instead I get no results at all:

```
<Where>
      <In>
         <FieldRef Name='page' LookupId='True' />
         <Values>
            <Value Type='Lookup'>5</Value>
            <Value Type='Lookup'>4</Value>
            <Value Type='Lookup'>3</Value>
         </Values>
      </In>
   </Where>
```

I rechecked the IDs a dozen times. They are correct. When I change the query to multiple OR-Operations it works fine.

Is this a known limitation of SharePoint 2010 or do I just have to insert a "magic" word somewhere?

Comment: make Type='Integer' instead of Lookup: `<Value Type='Integer'>5</Value>`,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

make Type='Integer' instead of Lookup: `<Value Type='Integer'>5</Value>`

Comment: hi, could you please advise how to make "IN" operator query with standard field FileRef in document libraries? thank you

Comment: @MichalHainc it should be the same way as written in the question, it shouldn't be any different for document libraries!

Comment: I tried both ways mentioned in the question with FileRef field which is supposes to be of type lookup (to which list though?) But it doesnt seem to work

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't read that you need to use "FileRef" field.. I will check once I'm on SharePoint environment and let you know